# is it possible to send image with message to facebook using url redirection

Tags: php, facebook, dialog, send

I'm able to send messages to facebook friends using url redirection but now I want to attach images with the message. I have tried to include a picture on the url but nothing happens.

If you know how to get this done please help me.

I send message successfully but image did not go with the message and I get this error on recipent inbox
 error:`This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you.`

this is the code I used

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['receiverid']))
{
    $fbfid=$_GET['receiverid'];
    header("location:https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?
    picture=http://www.educaptain.com/myecard.gif&
    message=jesus isgood&
    app_id=788167814543458&
    link=http://www.educaptain.com&redirect_uri=http://educaptain.com/egreetings-world/&
    to=$fbfid");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you can't send picture. See facebook documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

available parameters are :

- app_id
- redirect_uri
- display
- to
- link

NimS